# configure - check for availability of Perl headers (solved)

Tags: configure, autotools, autoconf

I'm developing an open source application where I'd like to include Perl conditionally (for different text processing purposes - that's just for information, not to be criticized as a concept :-). How would you normally check for availability of Perl headers using autoconf?

In my `configure.ac` I use the following for stuff that has pkg-config files:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GTK, gtk+-3.0, [AC_DEFINE([HAVE_GTK_3], 1, [Define to 1 if GTK+ 3 is present])])
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(SQLITE, sqlite3, [AC_DEFINE([HAVE_SQLITE], 1, [Define to 1 if SQLite is present])])
```

Unfortunately AFAIU Perl doesn't ship any `.pc`-s. In my `Makefile.in` to generate compiler flags I use their `perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts -e ldopts` instead of executing `pkg-config`.

Here rises the question - how would you do this in a prettier way?

I tried this:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADER([perl.h], AC_DEFINE(HAVE_PERL, 1, [Define to 1 if Perl headers are present]))
```

But it doesn't work unfortunately:

```
checking for perl.h... no
```

In my system (and probably much everywhere else) it's not in just `/usr/include`:

```
gforgx@shinjitsu nf $ locate perl.h | tail -n 1
/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/perl.h
```

Is there at all a 'legal' way to extend search path for AC_CHECK_HEADER *without using automake and AM_ macros*?

So far I tried manipulating CPPFLAGS, and it's much better but still (probably due to other inclusions in perl.h):

```
configure: WARNING: perl.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: perl.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: perl.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: perl.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: perl.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
configure: WARNING:     ## ------------------------------------ ##
configure: WARNING:     ## Report this to gforgx@protonmail.com ##
configure: WARNING:     ## ------------------------------------ ##
checking for perl.h... no
```

Many thanks!

### Update

Finally this works:

```
PERL_CPPFLAGS=`perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts`
PERL_LIBS=`perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ldopts`

old_CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS"
old_LIBS="$LIBS"
CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS $PERL_CPPFLAGS"
LIBS="$LIBS $PERL_LIBS"

# TODO: figure out why first option doesn't work
#AC_CHECK_HEADER([perl.h], AC_DEFINE(HAVE_PERL, 1, [Define to 1 if Perl headers are present]))
AC_CHECK_FUNCS(perl_construct, AC_DEFINE(HAVE_PERL, 1, [Define to 1 if Perl headers are present]))

CPPFLAGS="$old_CPPFLAGS"
LIBS="$old_LIBS"
```

Comment: How do your sources `#include` the header?  Is it "`#include <perl.h>`"? Or "`#include <perl5/CORE/perl.h>`"?  Or something else?

Comment: It is "<perl.h>".

Answer (score 1):

Not much of an autoconf expert, but I think: you can put plain shell snippets like

```
PERL_CFLAGS=`perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts`
PERL_LDFLAGS=`perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ldopts`
```

into your configure.ac. Probably the right way to do it is to use `AC_ARG_WITH` to let the user specify those vars, and only get them from EU::E if the user hasn't overridden them. (likewise you can use one to have `--with-perl` override the HAS_PERL check entirely).

Then you can use `AC_SUBST` to make the values from configure-time available in the Makefile (so you don't need to call EU::E in Makefile.in).

And finally, the heart of the issue, I don't think there's a *nice* way to make `AC_CHECK_HEADER` aware that it needs some nonstandard flags, but you can do

```
old_CFLAGS="${CFLAGS}"
CFLAGS="${PERL_CFLAGS}"
AC_CHECK_HEADER(...)
CFLAGS="${old_CFLAGS}"
```

to run AC_CHECK_HEADER with PERL_CFLAGS in effect.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that I can use pure Shell in `configure.ac` - I didn't know it's possible!

Finally I ended up with this (see the original post). The main thing here is that I needed proper `LIBS`. The question still is why `AC_CHECK_HEADER` doesn't work - but `AC_CHECK_FUNCS` does (I've found this in some other project's `configure.ac`).

Answer (score 0):

Note that you need Perl's C header(s) only if you want to build a Perl extension or embed a Perl interpreter in your binary.  The latter seems more likely to be what you have in mind, but in that case, do consider whether it would work as well or better to simply use an external Perl interpreter, launched programmatically by your application at need.  Use of an external Perl interpreter would not involve the C header at all.

However, you seem already committed to binary integration with Perl.  In that case, `configure` is the right place to test for the availability and location of Perl's development headers, and to determine the appropriate compilation and linker flags.  Putting it there also gives you the ability to use Automake conditionals to help you configure for and manage both with-Perl and without-Perl builds, if you should want to do that.

To that end, even though Autoconf does not provide built in macros for Perl detection / configuration, [the Autoconf Archive](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/) has a few of them.  In particular, [`ax_perl_ext_flags`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_perl_ext_flags.html) self describes its behavior as ...

> Fetches the linker flags and C compiler flags for compiling and linking programs that embed a Perl interpreter.

... which I take to be appropriate for your purposes.  After adding that macro to your project, you might incorporate it into your `configure.ac` like so:

```
PERL_CFLAGS=
PERL_LDFLAGS=
AX_PERL_EXT_FLAGS([PERL_CFLAGS], [PERL_LDFLAGS])

# ...

AC_SUBST([PERL_CFLAGS])
AC_SUBST([PERL_LDFLAGS])
```

That macro uses a technique similar to what you describe doing in your `Makefile.in`, but in a rather more robust way.

As for checking on the header, once you have the appropriate C compiler flags for Perl, you put those into effect (just) for the scope of the header check.  This is necessary because `configure` uses the compiler to test for the presence of the header, and if the compiler requires extra options (say an `-I` option) to find the header at compile time, then it will need the same at configuration time. Something like this, then:

```
CFLAGS_SAVE=$CFLAGS

# Prepend the Perl CFLAGS to any user-specified CFLAGS
CFLAGS="${PERL_CFLAGS} ${CFLAGS}"

# This will automatically define HAVE_PERL_H if the header is found:
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([perl.h])

# Restore the user-specified CFLAGS
CFLAGS=$CFLAGS_SAVE
```

Comment: Thanks for telling about AX_PERL_EXT_FLAGS and Autoconf Archive as such! I didn't know about the latter! :)

However, yes, I think I have solved the issue the same way, but without the macro (see the original post). Still - not sure why AC_CHECK_HEADERS doesn't work, while AC_CHECK_FUNCS does :-)

Comment: @SergeyS., `configure` produces an output file, `config.log`, that may help you with that question.  It should at least show you what commands were executed to perform the test, and if any of them failed then it will probably give you some detail about that.  Note well that this is definitely something to look into, because if the header is not detected by `configure`, then there's a good chance that it doesn't get detected when you're performing the build, either.

Comment: @SergeyS. also, a technical detail: you should *pre*pend the extra Perl flags to the user's flags (from `CFLAGS`) when you perform such a test, because that's analogous to how the flags will be ordered during the build, and flag order sometimes matters.  In your update to the question, you appear to be *ap*pending instead.

Comment: Thanks for both tips! Especially regarding `config.log`!
Yes, you're correct - I'll fix it before it's going public :) Added a FIXME note :)

Comment: P.S. Will definitely check difference between `AC_CHECK_HEADERS` and `AC_CHECK_FUNCS` in `config.log` and comment here.

Comment: P.P.S. Fixed that part (to prepend instead of appending) in my source code :-) Many thanks!